# AngularJS and UI-Router: 'Error: transition superseded' during angularjs unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I'm attempting to create an authorization package for a project of mine. I'm getting the error 'transition superseded' during my unit tests, and I can't find out where that would actually be.

Unit test:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';
import worldManagerApp from '../../src/world-manager-app';
import security from '../../src/security/security';

const {inject, module} = angular.mock;

describe('LoginService', ()=> {
    let $httpBackend;
    let $rootScope;
    let successHandler;
    let errorHandler;
    let LoginService;

    const USER = {username: "TEST", password: "PASSWORD"};

    beforeEach(function() {
        module(worldManagerApp);
        module(security);

    });

    beforeEach(inject((_$httpBackend_, _LoginService_, _$rootScope_) => {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        LoginService = _LoginService_;

        successHandler = jasmine.createSpy('successHandler');
        errorHandler = jasmine.createSpy('errorHandler');
    }));

    it('should exist', () => {
        expect(LoginService).toBeDefined();
    });

    describe('.login()', () => {

        describe('when given a proper username and password', () => {
           it('should return the username and success', () => {
               $httpBackend.expectPOST('/login').respond(200, {user: USER});
               LoginService.login("TEST", "PASSWORD");
               $rootScope.$digest();
               $httpBackend.flush();

               expect($rootScope.currentUser).toEqual("TEST");
           });
        });
    });

});
```

Service:

```
export default function LoginService($http){
    'ngInject';

    let service = {};
    service.login = login;

    function login(username, password){
        $http({
            url:'/login',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password,
            },
        }).then (function(response) {
            response.username;
        }).catch(function(response){
        });
    }

    return service;
}
```

Error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) LoginService .login() when given a proper username and password should return the username and success FAILED
        Error: transition superseded
            at C:/Users/Manifest/AppData/Local/Temp/353229d8bf0abe298e7003bab30c0528.browserify:9387 <- node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:261:0
            at processChecks (C:/Users/Manifest/AppData/Local/Temp/353229d8bf0abe298e7003bab30c0528.browserify:33750 <- node_modules/angular/angular.js:16674:0)
            at C:/Users/Manifest/AppData/Local/Temp/353229d8bf0abe298e7003bab30c0528.browserify:35048 <- node_modules/angular/angular.js:17972:0
            at C:/Users/Manifest/AppData/Local/Temp/353229d8bf0abe298e7003bab30c0528.browserify:34862 <- node_modules/angular/angular.js:17786:0
            at C:/Users/Manifest/AppData/Local/Temp/353229d8bf0abe298e7003bab30c0528.browserify:521 <- frontend\test\security\loginService.spec.js:42:15
```

I assume it's a ui-Router problem, but I can't figure out how it should work if I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same issue after update angular from 1.5.9 to version 1.6.1 and could solved it by update the dependencies with:

```
npm update angular-ui-router
```

The old version 0.3.1 leads to the error, with the updated version 0.3.2 my app works fine again (now with angular 1.6.1).

Comment: This worked for me earlier, when trying it for a different app it is nt working.errors are still seen

Comment: Upgrading the ui-router fixed the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 29):

When **updating** to **angular 1.6.1** that's the message, but **upgrading** the `ui-router` to **0.3.2** fix the problem

Comment: Also upgrading ui-router worked for me. I had (don't know how so old..) v0.2.18 and upgraded to the last v1.0.19.

Comment: for angular 1.8.0 version angular-ui-router 1.0.0 will work fine.

Answer (score 8):

This could be an error with your routing logic. If not that, then try adding this to your **app.config()**;

`$qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false)`

Comment: This worked for me. I updated angularjs to version 1.6.4, and started getting errors "transition superseded". Then I updated ui-router to version 0.3.1 and I was still getting errors. Then added this $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false) to my app.config([$qProvider]... and now I'm not getting any errors. 

However, the question remains, **does this fix the issue?** 
Thanks @Cengkuru Michael