# AngularJs Ui-routing transition superseded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

[image: Console for transition superseded]

i find the solution [AngularJS and UI-Router: 'Error: transition superseded' during angularjs unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450712/angularjs-and-ui-router-error-transition-superseded-during-angularjs-unit-te) but this not work for me.
AngularJs version v1.6.1
Ui-routing Version v0.3.2

Comment: how did you added the libraries ? if bower ? delete it in bower components and reinstall the libraries

Comment: added libraries using npm.

Comment: check if you have the correct version in the npm folder and coud you please add more of your code or create jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it.

In my project, root state is login state if login is successful then it goes to `admin.dashboard` state, where admin state was an abstract state.

I used`$state.transitionTo` method instead of `$state.go` when transitioning to the `admin.dashboard` state.

I've also added on app.config section.

`$qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);`