# ui-view not working angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I configured a route using ui-route as follows,

```
var app = angular.module("productManagement",
                        ["common.services",
                         "ui.router",
                         "productResourceMock"]);

app.config(["$stateProvider",
    function($stateProvider){
            // Products
            $stateProvider
            .state("productList", {
                url: "/products",
                templateUrl: "app/products/productListView.html",
                controller: "ProductListCtrl as vm"
            })

    }]
);
```

below is my index.html

```
<body ng-app="productManagement">
  <div class="container">
      <div ui-view></div>   
  </div>
</body>
```

it is not showing any error in console, and no views shown at all !!?
it used to work fine just before adding the route

this is part of the course AngularJS Line of Business Applications from www.pluralsite.com by Deborah Kuratah episode 26 "setting up the routing"

Comment: Do you definitely have `productListView.html` in the correct location: `app/products/productListView.html`?

Comment: just check if producListView.html is in the correcth path.

Comment: yes it is in the correct path : productManagement\app\products\productListView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to
 1. have a default route
 2. redirect to home if the state is not defined

```
app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider",
      function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
            // Products
           $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
            $stateProvider
           .state("home", {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "app/products/productListView.html",
                controller: "ProductListCtrl as vm"
            })
            .state("productList", {
                url: "/products",
                templateUrl: "app/products/productListView.html",
                controller: "ProductListCtrl as vm"
            }}  
     }]
   );
```

Comment: it worked after adding the default route, but now it is giving me  Error: transition superseded angular.min.js:124, any idea why?

Comment: Could be a number of things check this out if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450712/angularjs-and-ui-router-error-transition-superseded-during-angularjs-unit-te